# "Unable to deserialize request: Unexpected character ('j' (code 106)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cypher-3.1

I'm having trouble sending something to neo4j api.
This is the body of my request.

```
{
  "statements" : [ {
    "statement" : "Create (user:User{ name: "jon" }) Return user"
  } ]
}
```

I'm getting:

```
{
    "results": [],
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "Neo.ClientError.Request.InvalidFormat",
            "message": "Unable to deserialize request: Unexpected character ('j' (code 106)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries\n at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@7481578b; line: 3, column: 45]"
        }
    ]
}
```

**What is actually wrong with my code? Why would it expect a comma when i have only 1 property there?**

I've tried this: (nicer formatting)

`"statement" : "CREATE ( user:User { name: "jon" } ) Return user"`

Same error. Modeled after this:

`"statement" : "CREATE ( bike:Bike { weight: 10 } ) Return bike"`

Which works just fine. It's from the documentation.

The only difference is **the string.** But how else should i encode `jon` ?

because this:

`"statement" : "CREATE ( user:User { name: jon } ) Return user"`

Does not work either.

**I find this very counter intuitive.** 
Any help is appreciated :) And maybe you can provide some explanation of why this is necessary. Thank you :)

**EDIT**

Based on @cybersam answer - i realized i forgot to escape the string.

Yet this:

`"statement" : "CREATE (user:User{\"name\":\"jon\"}) Return user"`

produces this:

```
"errors": [
        {
            "code": "Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError",
            "message": "Invalid input '\"': expected whitespace, a property key name, '}', an identifier or UnsignedDecimalInteger (line 1, column 19 (offset: 18))\r\n\"CREATE (user:User{\"name\":\"jon\"}) Return user\"\r\n                   ^"
        }
```

My code get's produced automatically from `elixir maps` into `json`, using `Poison` module. I it doesn't seem to work to make Posion to give me `{ name : 'jon' }` as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSON string cannot contain unescaped double-quotes (").

Since Cypher accepts both single-quotes and double-quotes for delimiting strings, the easiest and most readable way to fix this is to use single-quotes for embedded string literals, like this:

```
"Create (user:User{ name: 'jon' }) Return user"
```

[EDIT]

*By the way: Don't bother to try to escape the embedded double-quotes, since that usually requires messy and hard to understand code. Trying to produce a string that contains escaped characters using a language or software that also uses the same method for escaping characters is not fun at all. Just using single-quotes is much easier (and should work for all languages).*

Comment: This makes sense. Although i tried escaping the double quotes as well - just forgot to mention - for example: `"CREATE (user:User{\"name\":\"jon\"}) Return user"`  I'm creating this json from elxir maps. I use the Posion module. I can't control what get's produced. Why is the `{\"name\":\"jon\"}` version not working? I will update my answer with this.

Comment: That is because you are trying to produce a string that contains escaped characters using a language or software that also uses the same method for escaping characters, which can really be mind bending to work around. What you end up with having to do to fix that is always extremely ugly and hard to maintain. Take the easy way out (which should also work for all languages) and use single quotes.

Comment: yes that's right. Hopefully i can. Elixir has structs, and maps and other special constructs - that get converted to json automagically by the Poison module. So far i could not find a way to produce the single quoted string values as shown by you. Still searching..

Answer (score 0):

The problem here comes form the fact that there were 2 problems:

First, When manual testing - i forgot to escape double quotes.

Second, in the actual program - i was encoding an already encoded elixir structure. Double encoding.

I was encoding this elixir map: `%{ name: "jon" }` into `{\"name\": \"jon\"}` json.

And then placing it inside a cypher query - which is a string: `"Create (user:User{\"name\": \"jon\"}"`

And then puting this string into the expected wrapper: `%{ statement : "Create (user:User{\"name\": \"jon\"}" }` which is an elixir map.

And then encoding this map into json again. The props are now escaped json inside json. I'm nuts!

**Solution:** 
**Insert the props into the `parameters` field.** Taken [from the neo4j http endpoing docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4-preview/http-api/#rest-api-execute-multiple-statements).

```
{
  "statements" : [ 
    "statement" : "CREATE (user: User{props}) RETURN user",
    "parameters" : {
      "props" : {
        "name" : "jon"
      }
    } 
  ]
}
```

Which is obtained from:

```
%{
  statements: [
    %{
      statement: "Create (user:User{props}) Return user",
      parameters: %{props: %{name: "jon"}}
    }
  ]
}
|> Poison.encode
```